# Very basic pyqtgraph histogram

Tags: python-3.x, histogram, pyqtgraph

I'm VERY new to Python (been working in it for only a day and with no previous programming experience), and for a project I'm looking to make a histogram within a dedicated window in an existing GUI. At this point I'm just looking for it to contain randomly generated data. I'm using `pyqtgraph`, `numpy`, and Python 3.

I've been trying to rework this code which i got to work and creates a scatter plot with random data and places it within my GUI window:

```
def upd_lowerplot1(self):
        """ Function to update bottom plot 1. """

        # Clear Plot
        self.ui.ui_botplot1.clear()
        # Now generate the plot
        x = np.random.normal(size=1000)
        y = np.random.normal(size=1000)
        self.ui.ui_botplot1.plot(x, y, pen=None, symbol='o')
```

I haven't found any examples on here or elsewhere that make much sense to me. If anyone could walk me through how to alter this code in baby steps that would be fantastic, trying to learn, not just get an answer with no understanding.